# Disconnected Satellite map tiles usable with OpenLayers or other JavaScript API

Tags: data, satellite

I'm looking for satellite map, usable with OpenLayers (or with another JavaScript API), with a good scale (at least 100m, MapQuest stops at 1000m) and available for a disconnected mode (available for download).

If I'm right Google forbids to download the tiles and only allows you to keep it in the browser cache, which in my case isn't efficient enough or too risky if the user clears his browser cache.

I'm not really good with terms of service, if possible something free or not too expensive.

Comment: Global coverage?

Comment: If possible but I'm mostly concerned by Maroco, Emirates, Uzbekistan and Kazakhstan satellite maps.

Answer (score 1):

You should see if using [ESRI's satellite imagery](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8663620) or [Mapbox's satellite imagery](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-satellite/) will work for what you need.

If not, I know [DigitalGlobe](http://www.digitalglobe.com) will sell you imagery, but I'm not sure how much it costs.

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS with Qtiles or QMetaTiles plugins to export MBTILES or geopackage. Or use gdal_translate with gdaladdo from within QGIS DESKTOP or command line. QGIS lets you connect to WMS,TILES IN WMTS, XYZ or TMS. Look at leaflet providers plugin for URLS for tile servers. Or a QGIS plugin that brings in tile servers. Don't violate their terms of use/service